Is there any future after PhD or future is bleak?
I was enrolled in a PhD program and was about to finish my thesis in mid-2020. I have a fairly strong publication record with three first-authored high-impact (aove 10) publications in top chemistry journals and a total of 20 publications (mostly second author). During the Covid lockdown, I slowly slipped into depression and could not extricate myself. Subsequently, I lost my father, and my mother also went into a nervous breakdown. I am finding it unbearable to finish the thesis and at the lost opportunity. Do I still have any future in academia as it's been almost 10 years since I started my PhD?

Would you comment briefly on the counseling you've worked through, and the advice you've received, in the meantime? Take care of yourself first. It's impossible for anyone to predict here if someone has a future in academia. That depends both on you and on the state of academia itself.

It would be helpful if you tell what field of science you are in.

I doubt that anyone online can answer this, but moreover, I would suggest that this is the wrong time to worry about this. Finish your PhD. After 10 years, it would be a tragedy if you did not finish. And once you are on the cusp of finishing, you can start to examine next steps.

moreover the implicit suggestion that a future outside of academia is “bleak” is rather shortsighted.

Yes, you have a future if you work toward it. The past is past and every day is the first day of the rest of your life. Counseling can both help with the past and give you strategies to avoid depression.
Try to make contact with former trusted professors and look to them for support as well as ideas.
The COVID era (not yet over) has set a lot of people back and others tend to understand that. But don't focus on explaining yourself to others. Work toward your goals. You may have to compromise, especially in this job market, as I did in a former terrible market, but if you look for opportunities, both in research collaboration and in job advancement, you can wind up in a good place. Ain't easy, but it works.
